# Save the position of a draggable div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have some draggable divs in my jsp which i can drag all around the page.After dragging there is one save button,On click of which i want to save the positions of grid in cookie or database whichever solution is better.Please suggest how can i do that.Below is my draggable code

```
<div id="drag">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                This div is draggable
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#drag').draggable();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Read the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) bro

Comment: @micheal do you want top and left positions ?

Comment: you can try localstorage

Answer (score 4):

Basically you want to take the X/Y coordinates and save them. This can be to local storage, set a cookie, send it to an API, it doesn't matter. But this is how you get the info.

```
<div id="drag">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>This div is draggable</p>
                <button id="saveMe">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (local.get('divOffset')) {
        //check if local storage already has your offset. and set it
        $('#drag').css(local.get('divOffset'))
    }

    $('#drag').draggable();

    $('#drag').on('click', '#saveMe', function () { 
        // we're listening for a click event on the saveMe button
        var $drag = $('#drag'),
        //assigning the #drag div jQ obj to a variable
            offset = $drag.offset(); 
        // grabbing the offset: Object {top: 157.5, left: 150}
        local.set('divOffset', offset);
        //save the offset(local storage)
    });

});

function Local () {
    return {
        set : function (key, obj) {
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
            return obj;
        },
        get : function (key) {
            var obj = {};
            if (localStorage.getItem(key) !== 'undefined') {
                obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            }
            return obj;
        },
        clear : function () {
            localStorage.clear();
            return this;
        },
        remove : function (key) {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
            return this;
        }
    };
}
var local  = Local();

</script>
```

The good about saving it to a database through an API service is that a user could go from computer to computer and their info will stay the same. local storage will stay persistent only on one machine. I've included local storage in order to give one example, as saving to an API is MUCH more involved.

This is a local storage getter/setter function I wrote a long time ago.

Comment: k.thanks man for help.I will see for api thing now fr inserting it in database

Comment: @micheal, what is your experience with server-side coding? I'm not saying you can't do it, but it's not a single-step process like this. You'll need a server to handle users(node), a database to store everything(mongo), and then a restful service that has endpoints to receive and send your div offsets. It's doable and there are lots of tutorials to help you out, but it's not easy.

Comment: well what i thought was getting the values from local storage i can insert them in database directly on click of save.Because I want it to be inserted on click of save button.So is this approach fine?

Comment: Yeah, localstorage is similar to cookies in that it is a key/value store. This is one type of database. So this should work perfectly for you. This does exactly what you want.

Comment: k.becuase at the moment i just wanted to save them in db which was my priority.So I thought of plain db approach as i mentioned in last comment

Comment: That's an overly simplified data persistence. There needs to be users/sessions/login/logout etc. in order for this to be useful for more than one person. Also, this still requires that you host a php server and mysql and know how to set them up. Doable. but once again, not exactly easy to build to scale.

Comment: ya i m currently working on java and oracle based server.So keeping all the things in mind.Thanks for valueable info

Answer (score 0):

- Here you have the jquery cookie plugin that you may use:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

- This is an example with jquery and php storing in a database.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-draggable-element-persistence-with-jquery--net-7474

- And here you have a working example with the jquery plugin storing as cookies.

**JS**

```js
jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
        options = jQuery.extend({}, options);

        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        value = String(value);

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
            options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || {};
    var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
};

//------------------------------------------------END of plugin!---------------------------------
$('div:first').draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { 
       $.cookie('div1x', $(this).css('left'));
       $.cookie('div1y', $(this).css('top'));
       }
});
$('div:last').draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { 
       $.cookie('div2x', $(this).css('left'));
       $.cookie('div2y', $(this).css('top'));
       }
});
if($.cookie('div1x') != null){
    $('div:first').css('left', $.cookie('div1x'));
}else{
    $('div:first').css('left', '50px');
}
if($.cookie('div1y') != null){
    $('div:first').css('top', $.cookie('div1y'));
}else{
    $('div:first').css('top', '100px');
}
if($.cookie('div2x') != null){
    $('div:last').css('left', $.cookie('div2x'));
}else{
    $('div:last').css('left', '150px');
}
if($.cookie('div2y') != null){
    $('div:last').css('top', $.cookie('div2y'));
}else{
    $('div:last').css('top', '250px');
}
```

```css
div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div></div><div></div>
```